# Is there a "Month picker" dialog in wxPython Phoenix?

Tags: wxpython

I need to pick a month, not individual day in wx.lib.calendar.
Is there a way to do it in wxPython 3.0?

For day selection I'd use this:

```
dlg = wx.lib.calendar.CalenDlg(self)
```

is there dialog that will let me click through months instead of days?

Answer (score 2):

You could always write your own:
Something like this?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import wx
class MonthDialog(wx.Dialog):
    def __init__(self, parent,title):
        wx.Dialog.__init__(self, parent, id=-1, title=title)
        self.panel = wx.Panel(self,size=(100,100))
        Months = ['January','February','March','April','May','June','July','August','September','October','November','December']
        self.month = ""
        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        self.Pick = wx.ComboBox(self.panel, wx.ID_ANY, choices=Months)
        sizer.Add(self.Pick,0,wx.EXPAND)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_COMBOBOX, self.OnPick)
        self.SetSizerAndFit(sizer)
        self.Pick.SetValue(Months[0])

    def OnPick(self,event):
        self.EndModal(1)
        self.month = self.Pick.GetValue()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App()
    dlg = MonthDialog(None, "Month")
    val = dlg.ShowModal()
    print "Dialog result: " + str(val)
    print "Month Selected: " + str(dlg.month)
```